# gcloud deploy fails with "Failed to enable APIs" error

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, gcloud

I followed this excellent tutorial on [Getting Started with Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/nodejs/#quickstart-deploy) but get the following error when running the last command `gcloud preview app deploy .`:

```
/Users/me/Google Drive/appengine-nodejs-quickstart> gcloud preview app deploy .
Updating module [default] from file [/Users/me/Google Drive/appengine-nodejs-quickstart/app.yaml]
08:51 PM Host: appengine.google.com
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Failed Project Preparation (app_id='s~foo-bar-123'). Failed to enable APIs.
--- end server output ---
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Command failed with error code [1]
```

I was able to run the app locally just fine using `gcloud preview app run .`. I checked and I do have Billing enabled for the project and some default APIs are enabled. Here's the results from `docker version` if it helps:

```
Client version: 1.3.2
Client API version: 1.15
Go version (client): go1.3.3
Git commit (client): 39fa2fa
OS/Arch (client): darwin/amd64
```

Any ideas what could be the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm an engineer on the managed vms team and have looked into the issue.  I believe the problem is we have changed our terms of service and you need to accept the before you can continue to use the product.  Obviously, our messaging in this case is bad and needs to be fixed.

For now you need to go to cloud.google.com/console, select your project, and accept the new terms of service.